# pyqt: How to let the QLabel occupy the whole window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I put three label in a window, however, the three labels only occupy small part of the window. Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class ThreeDMPRWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, image=None):
        super(ThreeDMPRWindow, self).__init__()

        self.resize(800, 600)

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        widget.setLayout(layout)


        allLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        label1 = QLabel('label 1')
        label1.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(255,0,0)")
        layout1.addWidget(label1)

        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        label2 = QLabel('label 2')
        label2.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(255,0,0)")
        layout2.addWidget(label2)

        layout3 = QVBoxLayout()
        label3 = QLabel('label 3')
        label3.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(255,0,0)")
        layout3.addWidget(label3)

        qlayout = QGridLayout()
        qlayout.addLayout(layout1, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        qlayout.addLayout(layout2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        qlayout.addLayout(layout3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        allLayout.addLayout(qlayout)
        allLayout.addLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        layout.addLayout(allLayout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = ThreeDMPRWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

If we annotate the code: allLayout.addLayout(QVBoxLayout()), the three labels would occupy the whole window. I don't know why this code makes such difference. But I can't remove the code allLayout.addLayout(QVBoxLayout()), because I need the new layout for some other widgets.

Comment: It looks like a bug, but I see that it is fixed if you add items to the QVBoxLayout(), have you added widgets to the QVBoxLayout()?

Comment: Yes, if I add a label to the QVBoxLayout, the window would be OK. But, I need the layout to be empty, because I would add some widget for the layout after some operators for user.

Comment: I understand you in part, do you initially want the right part not to be shown or just that it is empty?

Comment: I want the right part is empty.

Comment: see my answer...

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly answer, and it works. However, I find something interesting: the code would work if I change the  allLayout.addLayout(QVBoxLayout()) to allLayout.addLayout(QHBoxLayout()). Do you know why?

Comment: It seems to me that it is an undefined behavior of some of the variables that the layout handles, when I have time I plan to report it to Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a space where you can add other widgets then you must use QWidget instead of QVBoxLayout, and in that QWidget add the QVBoxLayout:

```py
# ...
allLayout.addLayout(qlayout)

empty_widget = QWidget()
empty_widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
lay = QVBoxLayout(empty_widget)

allLayout.addWidget(empty_widget)
layout.addLayout(allLayout)
# ...
```

Output:

[image]